# Assigning dynamic value to a global variable in kendo grid column template

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

Ok now I have this Kendo Grid code:

```
var ds = [
    { "ID" : 1, "attach" : "true", "attachment" : "http://www.google.com" },
    { "ID" : 2, "attach" : "false", "attachment" : "" },
    { "ID" : 3, "attach" : "true", "attachment" : "http://www.wikipedia.com" },
    { "ID" : 4, "attach" : "false", "attachment" : "" }
];

var $value = "asd";

var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({ 
    dataSource: ds,
    columns: [
        { field: "ID", Title: "ID", filterable: false, sortable: false, hidden: false },
        { field: "attach", Title: "Attached?", filterable: false, sortable: false, hidden: false},
        {
            title: "Attachment Link",
            template: '#if(attachment != ""){' +
                          '$value = attachment' +
                          '#<input type="button" class="info" value="IT WORKS" />' +
                      '#}else{#' +
                          '<label>NOPE</label>' +
                      '#}#',

            headerTemplate: "<label> Attachment </label>",
            sortable: false,
            filterable: false,
            width: 100
        }
    ]

}).data("kendoGrid");

//this is where I have been playing around trying to get the value. its not working. Shocker :D 
//I changed this part frequently, this is just the latest form I got it in. 

$(".info").on("click", function() {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var item = grid.dataItem(row);
        var show = $value;
        alert("The item is:" + show);
});
```

where I check if a column of a row has any non empty value or not, and if so I place a button there.

When I try to assign the value to attachment, ('value = attachment' part) I'm getting undefined as a result, but if I enclose attachment like this:

```
'#if(attachment != ""){#' +
                '#= attachment#' +
                '<input type="button" class="info" value="IT WORKS" />'
'#}else{#' +
                '<label>NOPE</label>' +
'#}#',
```

I can print the actual link assigned to it. How can I get the value of the attachments (individually, not as a list or array or sth) when I click the button associated with it?

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/phyrax/zz1h65f5/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kendo grid column template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.template) is a template for HTML content.

If you want to place some element in html code, you should use template. As I see, you want to execute JS code inside this template. To do this you should define `<script> $value = #= attachment# </script>` in your template.

Other question is what you want to do, because when you do something like this, it is executed for each row during page load. So the value of `$value` will be always set to last row.

EDIT to first comment:

You should consider to define template as

```
<input type="button" class="info" value="IT WORKS" onclick="setAttachment('#= attachment#')" />
```

and in global JS code define function

```
function setAttachment(attachmentValue)
{
   $value = attachmentValue;
}
```

This is more proper way to solve this task. Make action on click trigger, not immediately.

Comment: I posted the question prematurely, I edited it to be a bit more clear. My main concern is to get the link in the attachment field when I click the button. $value was just a way for me to try and get the link printed in an alert. I'm ok with it for now if I can just the latest one, but I'm getting undefined instead.

Comment: Ok, I defined the template as you showed, and defined the setAttachment(). I also added the alert() thingy in setAttachment and removed the $(".info").on("click", function()). Now the button isn't responding at all. Here is the latest fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/phyrax/zz1h65f5/3/)

Comment: Change `click` to `onclick` in HTML element. My mistake. It doesn't work in JSFiddle, but work in my local test page.

Comment: I assumed that would be the problem but when I tried 'onclick' it didn't work on the fiddle so I thought I'd just ask. I'll let you know when I try it out on the local page.

Comment: Yep. Worked on local. Thanks a lot!